# Why can't you improve tag-wiki edits?

Tags: feature-request, bug, suggested-edits, tag-management, tag-wikis

When reviewing post edits you have the option to <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> as well as <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd>.

These options are no longer available when a tag-wiki edit shows up in the queue (there have been quite a few recently). The reason for that is a mystery to me. I have been missing these options a couple of times.

As a way around so far, the only option to emulate the above seems to be either <kbd>Approve</kbd> or <kbd>Reject</kbd> (respectively) and then go and look for the tag to actually make relevant improvements.

Do we consider that someone making a tag edit is either spamming or careful enough to produce a perfect result? Or is that a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A user gets privilege to edit tag-info (without having to go through review) only [at 20k reputation points](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). It seems logical that only users with edit privileges get possibility to "improve edit" or "reject and edit". Here is a screenshot to show that at higher reputation these options are indeed offered:

[image: Screenshot]

See also related posts on Meta Stack Exchange: [Improve button in tag edition review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192253) and [If I can't improve a tag wiki edit, don't show me the button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81229).