# Why Suggested Edit review queue can be reviewed by me when my tag-edit itself has to go through Suggested Edits queue?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, tag-wikis

> Why Suggested Edit review queue can be reviewed by me when my tag-edit itself has to go through Suggested Edits queue?

Here I am talking about users with Suggested Edit privilege but don't have Edit Tag Wiki Privilege.

From my [previous deleted duplicate-question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34025/876009) I came to know that Suggested Edit queue in meta is for checking tag-edit of users having not the priviledge to directly edit the wiki tag. I do have access to review Suggested Edits queue. But I can't edit tag wikis directly without passing through queue. It shows

> You do not yet have [tag wiki edit privileges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.

Like in Main it makes sense when you can edit the questions and answers and review other edit. But in Meta it doesn't make sense like reviewing tag-wiki edit of other people when you yourself can't submit tag-wiki edit without going through review?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even on the main site, suggested edits to tag wikis will not show up in the Suggested Edits Review Queue to users who do not have the [approve tag wiki edits](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege, which is unlocked at 5,000 reputation. So, when you say

> Like in Main it makes sense when you can edit the questions and answers and review other edit.

you are missing the fact that users with at least 5,000 reputation may review tag wiki edits on main even without being able to directly edit tag wikis, since the latter is a [trusted user](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) privilege only unlocked at 20,000 reputation. (Do note that these users will only be able to either "Approve" or "Reject" the edit, but not "Improve": see [Why can't you improve tag-wiki edits?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28833/915354).)

So, if you want to make the case that users who cannot edit tag wikis ought not to be able to review them either, then that should be a request made uniformly for both, the main as well as meta, sites.

However, ignoring the main vs. meta comparison, it is still worth asking why there is a discrepancy at all between how editing and reviewing works for normal posts versus for tag wikis. This is raised in the post ['Tag wiki edit' privileges discrepancy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208188/986753) on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), and quoting from the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208189/986753) there by [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140890/martijn-pieters):

> Tag wikis see far less traffic and scrutiny. Editing a post bumps it up onto various pages, attracting a lot more visitors than a tag wiki edit ever does.
>
> As such, you need to have a far higher trust level before you are allowed to edit tag wikis without review.

Comment: You can approve or reject others tag-wiki edit when you yourself don't have edit privelege is same as saying you are checking other students maths paper when you yourself don't know the solution fully. Then why check? Hope you get the literal meaning

Comment: @JitendraSingh Rather, think of it as the community working collectively on crafting tag wikis. Some users suggest, others go over it and approve/reject. The reviewers may in turn suggest other tag wiki edits of their own, which will be approved/rejected by still other users. I personally don't see a problem with this aspect of the system.